# unable to include a ui_form header of QT5 in cmake

Tags: cmake, qt5

My CMakeLists.txt looks something like :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL Release)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
  SET (PROJECT_NAME location_recognition)
  message("Release mode")
else()
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
  SET (PROJECT_NAME location_recognition)
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FILES "-g -Wall")
  message("Debug mode")

endif()

#find QT libraries
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED)

# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# As moc files are generated in the binary dir, tell CMake
# to always look for includes there:
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
# We need add -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB when using QtWidgets in Qt 5.
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})

SET(SRC
  src/voting_classifier.cpp
  src/voting_classifier_helper.cpp
  src/results_scene.cpp
  src/image_window_widget.cpp
  src/image_result_matrix.cpp
  src/location_recognition.cpp
  src/main.cpp
  )

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

FIND_PROGRAM(QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE uic
  $ENV{QTDIR}/bin
  )

IF (QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE)
  # SET ( QT_WRAP_UI "YES")
  message("WOW")
ENDIF (QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE)

QT5_WRAP_UI(image_result_matrix.h ui_forms/image_result_matrix.ui -o ui_forms/image_result_matrix.h)
QT5_WRAP_UI(image_window_widget.h ui_forms/image_window_widget.ui -o ui_forms/image_window_widget.h)
QT5_WRAP_UI(location_recognition.h ui_forms/location_recognition.ui -o ui_forms/location_recognition.h)
QT5_WRAP_UI(ui_results_view.h ui_forms/result_view.ui -o ui_forms/ui_results_view.h)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ui_forms
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../perception_kit/utilities/include
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../perception_kit/visual_categorization/include
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

FIND_LIBRARY(utilities NAMES libperception_kitutilities.so PATHS "/other/workspace/perception/perception_kit/utilities/lib")
FIND_LIBRARY(utilitiesd NAMES libperception_kitutilitiesd.so PATHS "/other/workspace/perception/perception_kit/utilities/lib")

message("Utilites Libs :${utilities}")

FIND_LIBRARY(visual_categorization NAMES libperception_kitvisual_categorization.so PATHS "/other/workspace/perception/perception_kit/visual_categorization/lib")
FIND_LIBRARY(visual_categorizationd NAMES libperception_kitvisual_categorizationd.so PATHS "/other/workspace/perception/perception_kit/visual_categorization/lib")
message("Visual_categorization Libs :${visual_categorization}")

SET(LINK_LIBRARY optimized ${utilities} ${visual_categorization} debug ${utilities} ${visual_categorizationd})
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES SOVERSION ${perception_kit_VERSION} )
add_executable(location_recognition ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LINK_LIBRARY}
  ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBS})

qt5_use_modules(location_recognition Core Gui Widgets)
```

when i do

```
cmake .
```

it does fine. But when I try `make` it still says that the ui_forms/*.h header not found and it fails.

> In file included from
>   /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/src/results_scene.cpp:4:0:
>   /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/include/perception_kit/location_recognition/results_scene.h:6:29:
>   fatal error: ui_results_view.h: No such file or directory compilation
>   terminated. make[2]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/src/results_scene.cpp.o] Error 1
>   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/all] Error 2 make:
>   *** [all] Error 2

when i do `make VERBOSE=1'
I get

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake -H/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition -B/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/CMakeFiles /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition'
make -f CMakeFiles/location_recognition_automoc.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/location_recognition_automoc.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition'
cd /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/CMakeFiles/location_recognition_automoc.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition'
make -f CMakeFiles/location_recognition_automoc.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/location_recognition_automoc.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition'
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/CMakeFiles 9
[ 11%] Automoc for target location_recognition
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_automoc /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/CMakeFiles/location_recognition_automoc.dir/
AUTOMOC: Checking /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/src/voting_classifier.cpp
AUTOMOC: Checking /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/src/voting_classifier_helper.cpp
AUTOMOC: Checking /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/src/results_scene.cpp
AUTOMOC: Checking /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/src/image_window_widget.cpp
AUTOMOC: Checking /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/src/image_result_matrix.cpp
AUTOMOC: Checking /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/src/location_recognition.cpp
AUTOMOC: Checking /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/src/main.cpp
make[2]: Leaving directory `/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition'
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/CMakeFiles  9
[ 11%] Built target location_recognition_automoc
make -f CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition'
cd /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition'
make -f CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition'
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/CMakeFiles 3
[ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/src/results_scene.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE -I/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition -I/opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv -I/opt/ros/fuerte/include -I/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/include -I/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/ui_forms -I/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/include -I/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/../perception_kit/utilities/include -I/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/../perception_kit/visual_categorization/include    -o CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/src/results_scene.cpp.o -c /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/src/results_scene.cpp
In file included from /other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/src/results_scene.cpp:4:0:
/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition/include/perception_kit/location_recognition/results_scene.h:6:29: fatal error: ui_results_view.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/src/results_scene.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/other/workspace/perception/location_recognition'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So, somehow it is either able to create the ui_form header or its not linking properly. 
I spent quite sometime experimenting with QT_WRAP_UI and QT5_WRAP_UI but couldn't solve the issue. 
What should change in my CMakeLists.txt to get the ui_form headers included correctly ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You misused `qt5_wrap_ui` macro. According to [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html#qt5widgets-macros), it has the following parameters

```
qt5_wrap_ui(outfiles inputfile ... OPTIONS ...)
```

In your example, this become:

```
qt5_wrap_ui(UIS_HDRS
    ui_forms/image_result_matrix.ui
    ui_forms/image_window_widget.ui
    ui_forms/location_recognition.ui
    ui_forms/ui_results_view.ui
)
```

The command will configure your project to process *.ui files into valid C++ `ui_XXXX.h` and save their path to the list named `UIS_HDRS`. This allows you to use them as input of a target declared later:

```
add_executable(location_recognition ${SRC} ${UIS_HDRS})
```

Note: ui_XXXX.h files are generated in the build directory `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`.

Comment: Thanks ! That got rid of the .h file not found problem . But now I get "vtable not defined " problem for some of the functions. I already have set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON). Is there something more that needs to be added like CMAKE_AUTOMOC for ui_forms. ?

Comment: @navderm nvm found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761767/qt-5-cmake-fails-with-undefined-reference-to-vtable-on-hello-world-with-inc-sr