# ui header file (ui_name.h) not found

Tags: c++, qt

I've created form, saved it in project directory. And now i want to add some code.
So, I've created header file:

```
#ifndef SORTDIALOG_H
#define SORTDIALOG_H

#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>


#include "ui_sortdialog.h"


class SortDialog: public QDialog, public Ui::SortDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SortDialog(QWidget *parent=0);
    void setColumnRange(QChar first, QChar last);
}

#endif // SORTDIALOG_H
```

during writing code Qt creator see ui_sortdialog.h, and i, for example, can see "Ui" namespace. But when i'n trying to compiler writes that ui_sortdialog.h wasn't found

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\untitled2\sortdialog.h:8: error: ui_sortdialog.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ui_sortdialog.h"
                       ^
```

Comment: Did you add your ui file to the project like `FORMS += myform.ui`?

Answer (score 4):

You created a form called *sortdialog*, right?
If you did it using Qt Creator, it was supposed to add the following line to your project's .pro file:

```
FORMS += sortdialog.ui
```

If there is no such line, add it to the .pro file.

When a project has .ui files, a command called **uic** is called as part of the build process. This **uic** ("ui compiler") is responsible for the generation of ui_sortdialog.h, in you case.

You rarely need to call it directly, running qmake prior to make should do it for you (if the aforementioned FORMS line is in you .pro file).

Comment: how to check the ui header file generated by uic. I mean, where is the file saved?

Answer (score 3):

Qt sometimes experiences difficulties when the build directory is at the same folder as the `*.pro` file.

I suggest making sure that your build directory is one level higher in the directory structure than the project file.

The following directory structure is prone to error:

> MyProj/proj.pro
>   MyProj/builds/

The following directory structure will avoid this issue:

> MyProj/proj.pro
>   MyProjBuild/

Answer (score 3):

For people who come here that don't have a `.pro` file and don't use `qmake`, but `cmake`:

Instead of:

```
add_executable(myprogram
    gui.cpp
    gui.ui
    main.cpp
)
```

Use:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

add_executable(myprogram
    gui.cpp
    gui.ui
    main.cpp
)
```

Or:

```
qt5_wrap_cpp(UI_SOURCES
    gui.cpp
)
qt5_wrap_ui(UI_HEADERS
    gui.ui
)
add_executable(myprogram
    main.cpp
    ${UI_SOURCES}
    ${UI_HEADERS}
)
```

FYI: The `ui_gui.h` header will be generated at `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`. Sources:

- [unable to include a ui_form header of QT5 in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16359975/11942268)
- [Qt 5 cmake fails with undefined reference to vtable on hello world with inc & src as subdirs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19848720/11942268)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. 
  Here is what I had to fix:
Make sure that sortdialog.cpp and sortdialog.ui are **both** in the pro file in the appropriate sections with the appropriate case (upper or lower exactly as in the file names).